# Bash command to execute a foreground set of background commands

Tags: bash, unix, shell, shell-scripting, sh

I got 2 commands that run blocking the input in the console, so they must be ended with CTRL+C. I don't like running them in background, since I lost control for interruption. But otherwise I cannot execute them sequentially in a one-liner since first command waits for termination before next starts.

There must be a trick for this in unix. What I try is something like:

```
$ fg-wrapper infinite-cmd1 & infinite-cmd2
  Executing cmd1 in bg
  Executing cmd2 in bg
(Waiting for CTRL+C to end both)
```

**I am searching for a oneliner, not an script**: fg-wrapper is the built in posix command I would dream of provided as an example (I would like not having to script it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Executing $1 in bg"
eval $1 &
echo "Executing $2 in bg"
eval $2 &
wait
```

Explanation:

`$1` and `$2` refer to the first and second argument in the command line.
`eval` executes these commands with `&` running them in background.
Finally, `wait` waits for these commands to terminate or they can be terminated with CTRL-C.

Try this script with
`./script "ping google.com > /dev/null" "ping 127.0.0.1 > /dev/null"`

Comment: Is it possible to have this in a one liner form, not in script? Would `eval cmd1 & eval cmd2 & wait` work?

Comment: Nope it does not work, it does not kill the bg processes

Comment: What commands are you testing with? Are you using your one-liner or the script? I have since tried `evince` and `chromium-browser` which both worked.

Comment: With kubectl port-forwardinsg. Id like to open some of them and kill jointly with CTRL+C but with eval in the console, it just acts as if you executed bg, so the CTRL+C only applies to the wait. But I am using mingw on windows.. perhaps it has something to do..

Comment: Ill end up with something like `sleep 3000 & sleep 4000 & wait && pkill sleep`, but I am sure it must exist a nice built-in way

Comment: The type of shell might come into play. I have only tested with bash in Ubuntu. Maybe someone can help further test this in different environments.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! If noone suggestes better solution I will accept yours

Comment: This is a similar question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55558 Though the answer is similar.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the problem is  that when commands execute from within script usually there's different mechanics